# Can I set new root size on some element , not <html> ? (REM)

Tags: css, pixel, font-size, css-rem

**My problem is :**

Im using a CSS framework who using `rem` as unit. And some website/template set their `<html>` font-size like `html {font-size:62.5%}`, So **1rem is 10px not 16px** then all texts/elements who using that framework are small.

*Im trying to dont change their root font-size if possible.*

---

So question is : **Can I set a new root size on some element ?** (Possible ?)

**Something like :**

```
<html style="font-size:62.5%">
<!-- This and all children, 1rem = 10px -->
   <div class="helloworld-framework" style="font-size:16px;">
      <!-- This and all children, 1rem = 16px -->
   </div>
</html>
```

Comment: No, but you can reset the font size of the html element to the user's preference in your framework...